how to write a lexer rule in antlr4?
my antlr4 hello world grammar as below
grammar Hello;
r
    : 'hello' [a-z]+ EOF
    ;
WS
    : [ \t]+ -> skip
    ;

and then i use 'antl4 Hello.g4' command in cmd, but it throw exceptions:
error(50): Hello.g4:3:11: syntax error: 'a-z' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for rule element
error(50): Hello.g4:4:1: syntax error: mismatched input ';' expecting COLON while matching a lexer rule

but i found this code works well:
grammar Hello;
r
    : 'hello' ID EOF
    ;
ID  :
    [a-z]+
    ;
WS
    : [ \t]+ -> skip
    ;

could anyone help me please? thank you very much!

It's important to note how Antlr implements the lexer because you also have the STRING_LITERAL 'hello' in the grammar. So, how would hello hello be parsed? It can't. This is because STRING_LITERALs in the grammar are declared internally before other rules. So, the literal 'hello' would be defined as T__0 : 'hello'; and this rule place in a merged grammar at the top. grammar Hello; T__0:'hello'; r : T__0 ID EOF;WS : [ \t]+ -> skip;. The input is then tokenized as [T__0 T__0]. In other words, the second hello in input hello hello would be a T__0, not ID.

A character class, like [a-z]+, only works in lexer rules, not parser rules. That is why you get an error when you use it in r, but not when you use it inside ID.
